# Stick buttons to the right top of an scrollable div

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have a scrollable div element and some buttons that should stick at the right top of the div.

It's already working, but only for vertical scrolling. If I try to scroll to the right, it stays at the old position.

```css
.buttonsGroup {
  position: sticky;
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  right: 0;
  height: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}


.jsonArea {
  position: relative;
  overflow: auto;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #eeeeee;
  border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
```

```html
<main>
    <div class="jsonArea">
        <div class="buttonsGroup">
          <button>Button1</button>
          <button>Button2</button>
        </div>


      <div style="white-space:pre">
      EXAMPLE EXAMPLE EXAMPLE EXAMPLE EXAMPLE EXAMPLE
      EXAMPLE EXAMPLE EXAMPLE EXAMPLE EXAMPLE EXAMPLE
      EXAMPLE EXAMPLE EXAMPLE EXAMPLE EXAMPLE EXAMPLE
      EXAMPLE EXAMPLE EXAMPLE EXAMPLE EXAMPLE EXAMPLE
      EXAMPLE EXAMPLE EXAMPLE EXAMPLE EXAMPLE EXAMPLE
      EXAMPLE EXAMPLE EXAMPLE EXAMPLE EXAMPLE EXAMPLE
      EXAMPLE EXAMPLE EXAMPLE EXAMPLE EXAMPLE EXAMPLE
      EXAMPLE EXAMPLE EXAMPLE EXAMPLE EXAMPLE EXAMPLE
      EXAMPLE EXAMPLE EXAMPLE EXAMPLE EXAMPLE EXAMPLE
      EXAMPLE EXAMPLE EXAMPLE EXAMPLE EXAMPLE EXAMPLE
      EXAMPLE EXAMPLE EXAMPLE EXAMPLE EXAMPLE EXAMPLE
      EXAMPLE EXAMPLE EXAMPLE EXAMPLE EXAMPLE EXAMPLE
      EXAMPLE EXAMPLE EXAMPLE EXAMPLE EXAMPLE EXAMPLE
      EXAMPLE EXAMPLE EXAMPLE EXAMPLE EXAMPLE EXAMPLE
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
```

What im doing wrong here?
Every suggestion is welcome. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add these rules for `.buttonsGroup` selectors:

```
left: 0;
width: 100%;
text-align: right;
```

Also, delete `float: right`.

```css
.buttonsGroup {
  position: sticky;
  display: inline-block;
  /*float: right;*/
  right: 0;
  height: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: right;
}


.jsonArea {
  position: relative;
  overflow: auto;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #eeeeee;
  border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
```

```html
<main>
    <div class="jsonArea">
        <div class="buttonsGroup">
          <button>Button1</button>
          <button>Button2</button>
        </div>


      <div style="white-space:pre">
      EXAMPLE EXAMPLE EXAMPLE EXAMPLE EXAMPLE EXAMPLE
      EXAMPLE EXAMPLE EXAMPLE EXAMPLE EXAMPLE EXAMPLE
      EXAMPLE EXAMPLE EXAMPLE EXAMPLE EXAMPLE EXAMPLE
      EXAMPLE EXAMPLE EXAMPLE EXAMPLE EXAMPLE EXAMPLE
      EXAMPLE EXAMPLE EXAMPLE EXAMPLE EXAMPLE EXAMPLE
      EXAMPLE EXAMPLE EXAMPLE EXAMPLE EXAMPLE EXAMPLE
      EXAMPLE EXAMPLE EXAMPLE EXAMPLE EXAMPLE EXAMPLE
      EXAMPLE EXAMPLE EXAMPLE EXAMPLE EXAMPLE EXAMPLE
      EXAMPLE EXAMPLE EXAMPLE EXAMPLE EXAMPLE EXAMPLE
      EXAMPLE EXAMPLE EXAMPLE EXAMPLE EXAMPLE EXAMPLE
      EXAMPLE EXAMPLE EXAMPLE EXAMPLE EXAMPLE EXAMPLE
      EXAMPLE EXAMPLE EXAMPLE EXAMPLE EXAMPLE EXAMPLE
      EXAMPLE EXAMPLE EXAMPLE EXAMPLE EXAMPLE EXAMPLE
      EXAMPLE EXAMPLE EXAMPLE EXAMPLE EXAMPLE EXAMPLE
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
```